# Trace Network System Junction

Tags: arcgis-pro, geometric-network

I am just starting out using Trace Network after converting from Geometric Network. I am trying to figure out why my 'System Junctions' that appear at the end point of 2 lines with no valid point between them meet do not disappear after adding a valid point.

Steps to produce conditions:

1. Find 2 line end points that meet with no valid point feature present.
2. Add valid point feature at end points of said lines.
3. Validate the trace network.
4. The system junction error doesn't go away even though I now satisfied the rules set for the Trace Network.

Am I missing a step?

I have already run the 'Enable Network Topology' tool as well.

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.3. The data and Trace Network is located in a file geodatabase.

Comment: Back in ArcMap days you needed to "Rebuild" the network to make these points disappear. Perhaps there's a similar tool in ArcGIS Pro

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought the validate would do, but It doesn't appear to do anything as far as I can tell. In ArcMap my Geometric Network junctions would always go away on their own when you add a valid feature since I used it. I didn't use it until ArcMap 10.3.1 though.

Comment: This is an old question, but I found that in order to get trace network errors to go away after making edits to points or lines in the network I had to save my edits, validate the network, and then save edits again and validate again. that usually did the trick. I don't know why.